# jquery how to deal with mouseover or mouseenter events in layered SVG objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

In this small example of my problem, I want to be able to trigger events on mousing over my overlayed SVG objects.  In my hypothetical software, users would be able to create freeform SVG polygons that may overlap, with annotations associated with each.  When moving through these polygon SVGs, I want to switch focus to whatever new SVG is hovered over (no matter the position), without oscillating between them.

In this example here, I want to move the big SVG object before the first element of the SVG contiainer on a mouseover, so that the smaller one can be brought into focus.  However, when I move through the smaller SVG, moving to the front triggers another mouseover for the big one, causing an endless oscillation.

Is there any way to cleanly handle this?

https://jsfiddle.net/o35906ty/2/

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function moveToBack(layerToMove) {
        //console.log(layerToMove);
    var Holder = $("#container");

    //layerToMove.remove();
    layerToMove.insertBefore(Holder.find(":first-child"));
  }

    $("circle").mouseenter(function(e){
    console.log("mousing over " + $(this).attr("id"))
    $(this).attr('fill', 'green')
    moveToBack($(this));
  });
    $("circle").mouseleave(function(e){
    console.log("mousing over " + $(this).attr("id"))
    $(this).attr('fill', 'orange')
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <svg id="container" height="100" width="100">
    <circle id="big" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" fill-opacity = .4 />
    <circle id ="little" cx="50" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" fill-opacity = .2 />
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You say you want to switch focus to the one you are moused over, but why would you want to move it to the back when that happens?

Comment: The idea is that I would get mouseEnter events occurring for every stacked SVG element, even if it was entirely contained by another SVG element.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get mouseenter events for every element under the pointer, no matter where it is in the stack, and even if it is hidden by another element?

Comment: Well, as close to that as I can get.  The idea behind this is being able to assign annotation events to SVG polygons that the user draws.  The problem is if a polygon is completely enclosed in another polygon.  Both annotations need to be able to be activated.

Comment: So you want the big circle to remain "active" when the pointer leaves it and enters the small circle?

Comment: No, I want the small circle to become active when the pointer goes from the big circle into the small circle.  Then, I want the Big circle to become active when the pointer leaves the small circle and goes into the big circle.  And then I want this to be true for any number of these dynamically sized polygons overlapping in any way.

The solution that I'm thinking, is to just create an associated absolute position div that will handle each shape's events.  Unfortunately, it would be rectangular and not conform to the shape, but at this point I'm willing to concede that much.

Comment: The behaviour you desire is the default behaviour of mouseenter and mouseleave.  See https://jsfiddle.net/o35906ty/9/

Comment: The problem that I wanted to solve is when little is over big.  I did figure out a solution though, and I'll post it in a minute.

Comment: Small **is** on top of big in my example.

Comment: I meant in HTML order.  The problem would be when the little one is drawn first, then it can't be reached via mouseover events due to the larger one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this, what I did was assign a bounding div to each SVG object.  When creating the SVG, I took note of each extreme in terms of left, right, top, and bottom pixel coordinates, assigned them to an absolutely positioned div, and generated a scaled z-index to automatically sort the SVG objects from small in the front to large in the back.  This allowed for all dynamically created stacked SVG annotations to be displayable and use DOM mouseover events which are much less finicky than SVG mouseover elements.